# Find a non free submodule of a free module over R which is not PID

Tags: modules, principal-ideal-domains

I try to solve following question.

Show that $R=\mathbf{Q}[x,x^{-1}]$ is not a PID. Construct a free module over $R$ having a non free submodule.

One may give some examples for free modules but not PIDs which has a non free submodule for different $R$s. For such $R$, i don't know the answer.

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}[x,x^{-1}]$ is a PID, so you will have trouble.

Comment: Why PID? Can you explain?

Comment: The ideal structure of your ring differs from that of $\mathbb Q[x]$ only in lacking an ideal $(x)$.

Comment: @Lubin Don't forget about $(x^2)$,$(x^3)$.. etc! The whole chain of ideals is changed. Don't we say that these ideals have "exploded" in this localization?

Answer (score 4):

Oops. Let me revise my answer. Perhaps I won't make such a silly mistake this time. :)

The polynomial ring $\mathbf{Q}[x]$ is a subring of $R$ (and is a known PID), and all ideals of $R$ are extended from $\mathbf{Q}[x]$. What this means is that an ideal $I$ of $R$ is of the form $JR$ where $J$ is an ideal of $\mathbf{Q}[x]$. In view of this fact, $R$ is a PID since $\mathbf{Q}[x]$ is.

To prove the above claim, let $I$ be an ideal of $R$. If we put $J = I \cap \mathbf{Q}[x]$, then note $J$ is an ideal of $\mathbf{Q}[x]$ and hence $J = (f)$ for some $f\in \mathbf{Q}[x]$. Then it's not difficult to show $I = JR$. But $JR$ is the ideal in $R$ generated by $f$.

In fancier language, $R$ can be viewed as the [localization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localization_of_a_ring) of $\mathbf{Q}[x]$ at powers of $x$ (we are inverting $x$), and the ideal structures of a ring and its localizations are tightly linked.